# focus on last message in chat list view when opening the chat page in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want when I click on the chat page to focus on the last message which is in list view builder I tried using the scroll controller and use

```
_controller?.jumpTo(_controller!.position.minScrollExtent)
```

in initState but it didn't work I got an error which says scroll controller not attached to any scroll view I guess this is because the page hasn't been built yet

and I tried to use this too

```
if (_scrollController.hasClients)
```

before the jump to method but nothing happened

so I tried

```
WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  if (_controller!.hasClients) {
    _controller?.jumpTo(_controller!.position.minScrollExtent);
  }
});
```

with and without hasClients but nothing happened too

here is my code

```
Expanded(
                                child: ChatDetailsComponents.messageBody(
                                    snap: snap));

  static Widget messageBody(
  {required AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snap}) {
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 80, 8.0, 0),
  child: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: ListView.separated(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            MessageModel messageModel =
                MessageModel.fromJson(snap.data?.docs[index].data());

            if (messageModel.userId == kUid) {
              return CurrentUserMessageWidget(
                  isVideo: messageModel.isVideo!,
                  isDoc: messageModel.isDoc!,
                  isPhoto: messageModel.isPhoto!,
                  geoPoint: messageModel.geoPoint!,
                  content: '${messageModel.messageContent}');
            }
            return OtherUserMessageWidget(
              geoPoint: messageModel.geoPoint!,
              isDoc: messageModel.isDoc!,
              isVideo: messageModel.isVideo!,
              isPhoto: messageModel.isPhoto!,
              recieverUserImage: messageModel.receiverImage!,
              content: messageModel.messageContent!,
            );
          },
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Components.kDivider,
          itemCount: snap.data!.docs.length),
    ),
  ),
);}
```

and I tried to remove shrinkWrap but my list disappeared

so how can I achieve that?

Comment: Have you try adding reverse: true to the listview?

Comment: yes and same problem